# WSL Extention Connection plug/ icon not showing in VSCode U.I

Tags: vscode-extensions

Please i need a help, My windows subsystem for Linux WSL connection Icon(><) has disappeared in the Vs Code User Interface and i cant even connect/disconnect again.

i have tried several approach of troubleshooting i.e: i have uninstalled and re-installed wsl extension. many times, Restart visual studio code etc, but problem still persist. My visual studio code version is up to date: 1.79.2. and a Windows Subsystem for Linux version :2,  I will be glade to receive some help from the community.